# Javascript is not not working due to unknown reason

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am using a custom optin form. Here is the code

```
<div class="form fix">
    <p class="form-text">Fill This Out and See Your<br>Timeshare Report</p>
    <form name="contactform" action="mail-script.php" method="POST">
        <label for="fname">First Name:
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
        </label>
        <br>
        <label for="lname">Last Name:
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" />
        </label>
        <br>
        <label for="email">Email Address:
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
        </label>
        <br>
        <label for="phone">Phone Number:
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
        </label>
        <br>
        <label for="phone">Alternate Phone:
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="aphone" />
        </label>
        <br>
        <label for="resort">Resort Name:
            <input type="text" name="resort" id="resort" />
        </label>
        <br>
        <label for="amount">Amount Owed? $:
            <input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" />
            <p style="font-size: 12px !important;margin-top: -14px;padding-right: 30px;text-align:right;">If Paid Off Leave Zero, Else Put Amount</p>
        </label>
        <br>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <div class="check-text fix">
                <p>I'm Considering To</p>
            </div>
            <div class="check-one fix">
                <input type="checkbox" name="call" id="" value="sell" />Sell It
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="call" id="" value="buy" />Buy It
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="call" id="" value="rent " />Rent It
            </div>
            <div class="check-two fix">
                <input type="checkbox" name="call" id="" value="cancel" />Cancel Mortgage
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="call" id="" value="ownership" />End Ownership
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="call" id="" value="give" />Give It Back
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="captcha">
            <img src="captcha_code_file.php?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>" id='captchaimg'>
            <br>
            <label for='message'>Enter the code above here :</label>
            <br>
            <input id="6_letters_code" name="6_letters_code" type="text">
            <br> <small>Can't read the image? click <a href='javascript: refreshCaptcha();'>here</a> to refresh</small>
        </p>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="" />
        <p class="submit-text">Ensure all fields are completed and correct, allowing you more benefits, while preventing abuse of our data.</p>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to add a popup javascript to show success message when someone submits the form , I am using this code for it

```
$('form').on('submit',function(){
    alert('submitted');
});
```

But due to unknown reason , this code is not working , Here is the page url
http://timesharesgroup.com/sell/index.html

P.S  My goal is to show a success message to the user when he submits the form , I thought javascript was an easy method but if You can comeup with a better alternative , I shall be really grateful
Currently the form works like this:

1. User submits
2. Page refreshes for him
3. I get an email with the submitted data

**********UPDATE*****************
[image]

Comment: Please add more detail than 'it doesn't work'. What have you tried to do to fix or debug it? Have you checked the console? Is jQuery.js included in the page? Has it loaded properly? Is you code running before DOMReady? Is the `alert()` showing, but the form is still being submit? Work with us here...

Comment: I added the code in the index.html just below the form. Check the updated question please.

Comment: If i'm not wrong jquery.js is missing

Comment: @Danyal `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that you have used is [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) and not [JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/). For this to work you will need to include `jQuery.js` in your head section. Add the following in your `<head>` tag:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

If you want to use JavaScript, you can do the following change:

Original: `<input id="submit" type="submit" value="" />`

Modified: `<input id="submit" type="submit" onclick="alert("success");" value="" />`